# How to create this shape without and with tracing using illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to create this shape without and with tracing using illustrator. Please see given Image.[image]

Comment: With the pen tool? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Seems to me like a simple shape that you can create with a handful of methods

Comment: I have issue only with refine edges using pen tool, I need smooth edges

Comment: @Billu G - you probably need to learn how to use the Pen tool. There are lots of tutorials online. There's a beginner tutorial here on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B_IQK7hMo0 (I have no affiliation with this youtube channel)

Comment: @BilluG: please don't vandalise your own question. You can make an edit to explain your issue more in depth or add more details. But make sure the answers already provided make sense for future passers-by. For more info see [editing a question or answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: If you're unhappy with the answers then maybe you should make an [edit] to include what you've tried.  Since you haven't shown any effort and we aren't a tutorial board I've closed your question.  If you continue to vandalize your question I will lock it the next time.  I'd suggest taking this time to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why my question is down-voted. I have asked legal question, and people answered and I have accepted answer.

Comment: @PieBie, please up-vote my question, as you have update it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lack of verbal fingers. But you get an answer, too. Draw it. Keep a copy of your shape as reference. It's tracing, but manually. The pen tool is not necessary in this case. Probably you learn something about the path anchors and their control handles. Without that knowledge the Pen is nearly useless.

Your shape was be copied and pasted to Illustrator from your question.

[image]

Comment: yes, I have tried and completed in first attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do this with the pen tool. No tracing, no shapes, no pathfinder, all of three points required.

- Drop your image in AI and lock it so you don't  accidentally select it.
- Create the three points and close your path by clicking the first point again.
- Convert all points to rounded.
- Drag the handholds to give the bezier the desired curve.

  - Unlink the bottom handholds by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> while dragging them.
- Fill your shape with the gradient tool.
- Done.

[image]